# telnet in windows 7, command overlapping

Tags: windows-7, telnet

I enable and use telnet on windows 7 for checking my server program I have created which read and write to client, I run it on localhost, but the problem is on windows's telnet, it's keep overlaping, so when I type in the command overlap the old command not move to 
next row.
can anyone tell me solution for windows's telnet or what software could I use to telnet my localhost?

Comment: You should be more specific. What program, what exactly happens, why telnet?

Comment: it sounds like a problem with your command prompt. do you ever get this when using cmd for things other than telnet? also remember you have to exit telnet between invocations of it. no idea if you are or not. please post a picture or at least the command prompt text.

Comment: yes, it's keep overlapping even using cmd.